# Error from server (NotFound): error when creating STDIN: namespaces gitlab-runner not found

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I am setting up CI CD pipeline using GitLab. The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file deployment section is given below.

```
Deploy to DEV:
  variables:
    GCP_PROJECT_ID: <>
    GOOGLE_IMAGE_NAME: <>
    CLUSTER_NAME: <>
    ZONE: <>
  image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh"  | bash
    - mv kustomize /usr/local/bin/
  script:
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
    - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --zone $ZONE --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - cd .k8s/overlays/dev
    - kustomize edit set image <IMAGE_NAME>=gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$GOOGLE_IMAGE_NAME:$VERSION-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - kustomize build . 
    - kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_request
      - master
  when: manual
```

It shows the error `Error from server (NotFound): error when creating STDIN: namespaces gitlab-runner not found`

But I have not defined any namespaces named `gitlab-runner`. The cluster don't have any namespace with that name. Where is this coming from?

Comment: Can you share what guide you follow to set up Gitlab? How was it installed?

Comment: Not really sure what steps were exactly followed. Gitlab is installed on a VM. Community edition. And the shared runners are running in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who is bumping into the same or similar problem, I finally was able to solve it by explicitly mentioning the `namespace: default` in the Deployment yaml. I thought since the Deployment was in the Default namespace I would not have to specify the namespace. But specifying it solved it for me.

I still don't know what's causing the issue though.

Comment: Alternatively you can use: `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=default`